# How do I make jackson not serialize primitives with default value

Tags: java, json, jackson

In Jackson, it is possible to use JsonSerialize annotation on a POJO in order to prevent null objects from being serialized (@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)).  Primitives, however, cannot be set to null, so this annotation doesn't work for something like an int that hasn't been touched and defaults to 0.

Is there an annotation that would allow me to say something like "For this class, don't serialize primitives unless they are different than their default values" or "For this field, don't serialize it if its value is X"?

Comment: Have you considered using a custom serializer? Not sure how it works with primitives, but at least take a look at it.

Comment: That was the answer I was hoping not to hear =).  Everything has worked really well so far with the vanilla setup and the JsonProperty, JsonIgnore, and JsonFilter annotations.

I'll check it out though, thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you're using a recent version of Jackson you can use [`JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT`](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_DEFAULT) which should work for primitives.

The downside to this approach is that setting a bean property to its default value will have no effect and the property still won't be included:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
public class Bean {
  private int val;
  public int getVal() { return val; }
  public void setVal(int val) { this.val = val; }
}

Bean b = new Bean();
b.setVal(0);
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(b); // "{}"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!  How recent does my version need to be?

Comment: Check your `JsonSerialize.Inclusion` or `JsonInclude.Include` (if using Jackson 2.x) enum for a `NON_DEFAULT` option, it looks like it's been around longer than I thought

Answer (score 7):

The fact is that in Java the class loader will set to the default value all not initialized primitive properties (int = 0, boolean = false etc...), so you can't distinguish them from those set explicitly by your app. In my opinion you have two options:

- Use corresponding wrapper objects instead of primitives (Integer,Boolean,Long..)
- As already suggested, define a custom serializer

Answer (score 1):

#### Class or property level: (You can also configure it globally or per-type basis as detailed [here](https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-tips-filtering-with-jsoninclude-27f08979514c))

`@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)`. //This is for primitives.
<s>@JsonInclude(content = JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)</s>.

#### In increasing order of precedence:

> 1. Global default: ObjectMapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(...) — used if no other settings apply
> 2. Per-class @JsonInclude annotation (specifies default inclusion for Class being annotated (overrides global default)
> 3. Per-type inclusion default: ObjectMapper.configOverride(MyValue.class).setInclude(...) which
>    similarly specifies inclusion for type specified (but overrides global
>    default and possible per-class annotation)
> 4. Per-property inclusion override: @JsonInclude on property accessor (field, setter/getter, constructor argument) — overrides defaults from
>    other 3 levels