# @jsondeserialize does not work when json value is null

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

@JsonDeserialize does not work for null json value in this case. it is throwing error

// I have the following json string.

```
            {
                "myCount": null
            }
```

//class

```
                public class Test {
                  // @JsonDeserialize does not work for null json value in this case. it is throwing error.
                 @JsonDeserialize (using = Custom.class)
                 private double myCount;
            }
```

//Custom deserializer

```
             public class Custom extends JsonDeserializer<Double> {
                //implements deserialize method
                @Override
                public Double deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                String text = jp.getText();
                if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
                 return null;
                } else {
                return Double.valueOf(text);
                }
                    }
                }
            }
```

please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that you are using a primitive `double`, then Arashsoft has your answer. However I suspect you will run into other problems.

It looks to me like your deserializer does not do anything more than a default deserializer would do, so yours, as written, is unnecessary.

You are calling `jp.getText()` which will only return a `String` if your `JSON` value is in quotes, like `"myCount" : "123.45", but that's not what you want.

If you want to intercept the null that would normally be assigned to your `myCount` field, you have to override `getNullValue()` in your deserializer. The implementation will depend on the JSON library that your are using, but for me, this works:

```
package ca.mydomain.myapp.util;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationContext;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer;

public class JsonDefaultZeroDoubleDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Double>
{

    protected JsonDefaultZeroDoubleDeserializer () { this (null); }

    protected JsonDefaultZeroDoubleDeserializer (Class<?> vc)
    {
        super (vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Double deserialize (JsonParser sp, DeserializationContext dCtxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        return sp.getCodec().readTree (sp).asDouble ();
    }

    @Override
    public Double getNullValue ()
    {
        return 0.00;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your field is primitive double instead of Double. Therefore, it cannot accept null.

Change `private double myCount;` to `private Double myCount;` and it should work fine.

For more information regarding their difference please see [this link](http://www.datafusion.net/difference-between-a-class-type-and-a-primitive-type-in-java/).

Comment: is correct that the field has to be `Double` not `double`. However, if the value in the JSON is null, I do not believe the deserializer is called at all.

Comment: @PMorganCA, It depends on your setting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578846/ignore-missing-properties-during-jackson-json-deserialize-in-java