# How to consider a field only if it is sent as a post json request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
{
    "parentWinnerInactivePartyID": "",
    "childMergeLoserPartyID": "",
    "eventType": "M&A",
    "startData": "2020-01-03",
    "endDate": null,
    "eventDate": "01-03-2020 08:09:14",
    "status": null,
    "mnaID": "1",
    "newMNAendDate": null,
    "createdBy": "abcd"
}
```

I have another field called transactionKey and I want to send only for certain eventTypes. How do I modify the request accordingly. What do I need to define in my POJO class?

My POST request would be something like,

```
{
    "parentWinnerInactivePartyID": "",
    "childMergeLoserPartyID": "",
    "eventType": "M&A Redo",
    "startData": "2020-01-03",
    "endDate": null,
    "eventDate": "01-03-2020 08:09:14",
    "status": null,
    "mnaID": "1",
    "newMNAendDate": null,
    "createdBy": "abcd",
    "transactionKey": "Andsf1234"
}
```

Comment: I believe this StackOverflow link may provide you with the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578846/ignore-missing-properties-during-jackson-json-deserialization-in-java

Comment: Can you have transaction key as null like endDate and newMNAendDate accepting null in the POST request?

Comment: priyanka i can have null but the requirement is I need to make it optional field. Some events might have this request and some might not have this request

Comment: Filippo Possenti - This is at the class level and can help in changing the way response is sent and include only non null response. But i need for the request.