# Change httpresponse with DTO

Tags: java, api, httpresponse, dto

I run in container fake smtp and it has own api, but it's not readable and i dont need like 80% of response, so how i can use DTO to make response more readable and less verbose?

```
 HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:port/api/v2/messages"))
                .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

it responses huge json, i need to implement my DTO to make it more readable and remove unnecessary parts of json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but...

As found as an answer for this question: [Ignore missing properties during Jackson JSON deserialization in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578846/ignore-missing-properties-during-jackson-json-deserialization-in-java)

You can just add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` to ignore every field you did not specifically asked for in your DTO.

You can then convert your json to your object jackson like so

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
return objectMapper.readValue(response.body(), YourDTO.class);
```

where `response` is your HttpResponse.