# Make one property in request body not required

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following interface:

```
public interface TestRequestView {
  String getCountryCode();
  String getRegionCode();
}
```

It's used in several end points like so:

```
@PostMapping("/my/path/{id}")
public String test(@RequestBody TestRequestView request, @PathVariable String id) {
 ...
}
```

I would like to add a property to the TestRequestView that is only used in one new endpoint without breaking the rest, how can I mark that one property as ignorable? Something like:

```
public interface TestRequestView {
  String getCountryCode();
  String getRegionCode();
  String getEmail(); // make this not required
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Usually it is better to use 1 such a model per endpoint so they are independent. If you share models between endpoints [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) should be useful
2. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578846/ignore-missing-properties-during-jackson-json-deserialization-in-java) may help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation

Example:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"email"})
public interface TestRequestView {
  String getCountryCode();
  String getRegionCode();

  @JsonProperty(required = false)
  String getEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add annotation `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` at class level for your `TestRequestView`. When passing your param you can pass it without that value and in your controller it will be received with that param as null. You just need to make sure that your controller can handle such case

Comment: If i'm not mistaken Jackson fails by default on undefined properties

Comment: @ŽekaKoževin you are right. I updated the answer to use annotation @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)

Comment: it's not the case @MichaelGantman - it will fail during deserialization, not serialization.

Comment: @bpawlowski no, it works both ways